# Why does Unix.SE give me this message and no other SE sites do?

Tags: support, user-interface, voting

Whenever I visit a question on Unix.SE, I get the following message:
[image: Vote Up]

On any other SE site, I don't get it.  When I click close this message, the next time I visit a question, I get the same message.  Why is this, and can I turn it off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/91564/213575)

> This isn't a bug, this is [by design](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89045/disable-dont-forget-to-vote-message/89059#89059):
>
> > Welcome back! If you found this question useful, don't forget to vote both the question and the answers up.
>
> only appears if
>
> - **you haven't been seen on the target site for 48 hours**
> - you hold a valid user cookie on the target site
> - your account has more than 15 rep on the target site
> - you arrive on a question from a search engine
>
> If you are a very infrequent visitor, yet tend to hit a lot of web
>   search results... you might want to log out. **But you really should
>   be voting up all those search results if you found them, and they are
>   helping you!**

Comment: Thanks, I usually do vote on questions.  Anyway, it just seemed like it happened many times in a day.  Maybe a glitch?